# Сортировка по регулярному выражению

Tags: python

На выходе хочу получить список в котором сортировка осуществляется по MAC.

```
def DB():
    l = get_essid_mac_http()
    mac_re = r'([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})'
    for s in l:
        if len(s) is 2:
            x = sorted(s,key=lambda x: mac_re)
            print(x)
```

Пример входных данных:

```
[['RTK-310540', 'A8:F9:4B:C3:A1:19'], ['RTK-310540', 'A8:F9:4B:C3:A1:19'],[ 'A8:F9:4B:C3:A1:19','RTK-310540',]]
```

Не могу понять, почему не работает сортировка?

Comment: приведите образец списка на входе, и что вы хотите получить

Comment: @splash58, [['RTK-310540', 'A8:F9:4B:C3:A1:19'], ['RTK-310540', 'A8:F9:4B:C3:A1:19']] пример входных данных.
На выходе хочу получить список в котором сортировка осуществляется по MAC'у.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Answer (score 1):

> Не могу понять почему не работает сортировка

потому что функция [sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) в качестве параметра `key` ожидает функцию, а вы ей передаете лямбда функцию, возвращающую константную строку:

```
In [65]: print(mac_re)
([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}

In [66]: print(type(mac_re))
<class 'str'>

In [67]: type(mac_re)
Out[67]: str
```

что эквивалентно следующему:

```
In [60]: def f(x):
    ...:     return mac_re
    ...:

In [61]: f("bac")
Out[61]: '([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\\-]?){6}'

In [62]: f("cab")
Out[62]: '([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\\-]?){6}'

In [63]: f("abc")
Out[63]: '([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\\-]?){6}'
```

Comment: Там все плохо - в регулярке стоит шесть повторов, в ифе проверяется на длину 2

Comment: @splash58, возможно `s` - список или кортеж. Но без примера данных остается только гадать...

Comment: @MaxU, s - это список.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужны регулярки

```
res = sorted(l,key=lambda x: x[1])
print(res)
```

---

ищем при помощи регулярки mac и возвращаем его в качестве ключа сортировки

```
def f(x) :
    for i in x:
        if re.match(r'([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})', i):
            return i
    return ''


res = sorted(l, key=f)
print(res)
```

Comment: Пометка по входным:
MAC не всегда занимает второе место в списке он может находиться и на первом
Пример:
[ 'A8:F9:4B:C3:A1:19','name']

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: @Ulius_n4  _MAC не всегда занимает второе место в списке_ - вы привели пример входных данных в вопросе. Соответствуют ли они действительности?

Comment: @0xdb, Исправил пример.